# WLST: ERROR: You must specify the destination port correctly

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I trying to connect to oracle using WLST, but I got an error

```
C:\Tools\wls12130\oracle_common\bin>connect('weblogic', 'welcome100', 'localhost:7001')
ERROR: You must specify the destination port correctly.
usage: connect [-dnhst45] [-p local-port]
          [-H proxy-server[:port]] [-S [user@]socks-server[:port]]
          [-T proxy-server[:port]]
          [-c telnet-proxy-command]
          host port
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are invoking a connect command from you DOS shell and not from WLST.
First, run WLST C:\Tools\wls12130\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd and then run your connect command.